# I want to Export the data/content of DataGrid to Pdf & csv file in UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp

There is no any such specific answer for **UWP** implementation that will give me the correct solution.

I have a datagrid which will have data from it's item source.

Solution tried:- Export To PDF in UWP DataGrid (SfDataGrid) - Syncfusion.
Tried this as well:- Export DataGridView Data To PDF In C# - C# corner solution.

I just want to save the datagridview and its content to pdf or csv on my local memory.

Is there a direct and simple way for this implementation without the need/help of 3rd party controls?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to Export the data/content of DataGrid to Pdf & csv file in UWP application

I think you have not to save the datagridview to csv, you could save the datasoure collection to csv indirectly. please refer to csv [document](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#writing-a-csv-file) writing a csv file.

```
var csvfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.csv", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

var records = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(csvfile.Path))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Please note the stream writer path should be UWP [local folder path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/fileio-learning-track) that has full access permission.